# UIViewController: viewWillAppear is called, viewDidAppear not

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

In a UIViewController subclass, I have the following methods:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // do something
    myTextField.text = @"Default";
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // do something
    [myTextField selectAll:self];
    [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    // do something
    myTextField.delegate = self;
}
```

The NIB has been created using Interface Builder. The corresponding view controller object is pushed by the navigation controller through pushViewController.

The inteded behavior is to show a default text entry in a text field, to select the entire text and to set the text field as first responder. [Edit: I've noticed that selecting all *and* making first responder makes no sense as the selection would dissapear; still, I wonder why the methods behave as described next.]

However, **while methods viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear are called, the method viewDidAppear is not called.** Can anybody tell me why? Most questions I found on the web and here deal with both viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear are not working; I also understood that in subviews or programmatically created views these methods are not evoked; but this does not apply in case and also I wonder why one of these "lifecycle" methods is evoked and the other not.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

I had this issue happen to me: `viewWillAppear` was being called but `viewDidAppear` was not!

I finally figured out that this was because I had a `tabBarController` where I overloaded it's own `viewDidAppear` and forgot the `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`

It threw off every `VC` in every tab! adding that line back in fixed it for my other `VC's`.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This was the exact case for me in my Swift project. Thanks!

Comment: This was the exact case for me in my Swift project. Thanks! –

Answer (score 2):

There is one case when `viewWillAppear` will be called but `viewDidAppear` will not.

Suppose you have two `viewControllers` and you push from the first to the second controller. Then, using the swipe, you want to go back to the first one, both controllers are displayed at the same time and at that moment `viewWillAppear` will be called from the first controller.

This way, you do not finish the swipe and stay on the second controller and `viewDidAppear` will not be called from the first controller.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I had copy/pasted `viewDidAppear` to create `viewWillAppear` but had forgotten to change the `super.viewDidAppear()` call. This then seemed to stop `viewDidAppear` from being called.

It sounds like somewhere in your code you have missed or messed-up a call to the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `viewDidAppear:` should always follow `viewWillAppear:` unless you are doing something custom, which you say you don't. I don't know why it doesn't work but here are a few ideas:

Could it be that you are doing something strange in one of the delegate methods for `UITextFieldDelegate`? It's unlikely that it would affect `viewDidAppear:` being called but it could be a culprit.

Have you loaded a lot of stuff into memory before pushing the view? I'm not sure what would happen if you got a memory warning between `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:`.

Have you tried to do a Clean? Sometimes that can help.

In cases like these when it should work I usually create a new class and the introduce the functionality one at a the time to see if I can get it work that way. I tried your code in a new Navigation Based project where I added a new `UIViewController` with an outlet to the text field. Then I pasted the code from the question and it did work as expected.

Comment: There should not be a memory issue, at least didReceiveMemoryWarning does not get called. A clean all targets did not help. So I followed your advice and I stepwise "copied" the class in a new project. And it works. :-/ I've added all methods I override in my original class and in one project it works, in the other it doesn't. In both cases the view is shown by pushViewController on a navcontroller. Only difference: in the test project there is one navcontroller, in my project there are three (rootcontroller is a tabbarcontroller)

Comment: @sven - I want to change the title view of navigation bar. It seems that the view has not yet been pushed to navigation bar when viewWillAppear is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because you added a child view controller to your parent VC in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. The child's appearance prevents the call to `viewDidAppear`.

This is a crazy thing to do, and I only know because this was a bug in my code. I meant to add the child VC to this VC, not the parent VC.