# Do segue every time navigationcontroller pops stack

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, segue

I have this class, with the following code. Basically every time this page is shown, an immediate segue should be performed after checking if the user is logged in or not.

```
   class UserExistsOrNotViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabBarController?.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.viewDidAppear(true)
        print("test")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let openSearchItem = realm.objects(User).count
        if openSearchItem == 0 {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("notLoggedIn", sender: self)
        } else {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: self)
        }

    }
```

The issue I'm having is that once I pop the previous page off the stack, and it returns to this code, the segue is not performed. If I place it under `viewWillAppear`, my navigation is corrupted.

> Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state.
>   Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted)

I'm not sure what to do now. What I'm looking for: when I pop my viewcontroller from the navigationcontroller, the class above should check each time whether the user is logged in or not, and segue to the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

If your ViewWillAppear is being fired, but ViewDidAppear isn't. Check that you aren't missing `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`. See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346154/uiviewcontroller-viewwillappear-is-called-viewdidappear-not)

Comment: Hi, I added it, but it didn't make a difference for the firing. I do however also have a tabBarController (where the code above is the first entry point)

Comment: Have you overridden the tabBarController's viewDidAppear?

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I updated the code